# java Spring factory-bean factory-method autowiring

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Java - Spring

I have spring factory bean creation in .xml

```
<bean id="concurrentHashMapFactory" class="com.abc.HashMapFactory.ConcurrentHashMapFactory"/>
 <bean id="idCorpMap" factory-bean="concurrentHashMapFactory" factory-method="createIdCorpMapInstance"/>
```

but i want to convert above .xml statement into equivalent using annotation any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Roughly like this (I didn't test it)..

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean(name = "concurrentHashMapFactory")
  public ConcurrentHashMapFactory createConcurrentHashMapFactory() {
    return new ConcurrentHashMapFactory();
  }

  @Bean(name = "idCorpMap")
  public IdCorpMapType createIdCorpMap(ConcurrentHashMapFactory factory) {
    return factory.createIdCorpMapInstance();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Bean does not allow params